# Getting router parameters using the Registry pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller, registry, router

I have this Router.php at the core of my application.

**Router.php**

```
<?php

final class Router
{
    protected $routes = [];
    protected $params = [];

    public function add($route, $params = [])
    {
        $route = preg_replace('/\//', '\\/', $route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>[a-z-]+)', $route);
        $route = preg_replace('/\{([a-z]+):([^\}]+)\}/', '(?P<\1>\2)', $route);
        $route = '/^' . $route . '$/i';

        $this->routes[$route] = $params;
    }

    public function getRoutes()
    {
        return $this->routes;
    }

    public function match($url)
    {
        foreach ($this->routes as $route => $params) {
            if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {
                foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
                    if (is_string($key)) {
                        $params[$key] = $match;
                    }
                }

                $this->params = $params;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }

    public function dispatch($url)
    {
        $url = $this->removeQueryStringVariables($url);

        if ($this->match($url)) {
            $controller = $this->params['controller'];
            $controller = $this->convertToStudlyCaps($controller);
            $controller = $this->getNamespace() . $controller;

            if (class_exists($controller)) {
                $controller_object = new $controller($this->params);
                $action = $this->params['action'];
                $action = $this->convertToCamelCase($action);

                if (is_callable([$controller_object, $action])) {
                    $controller_object->$action();

                } else {
                    echo "Method $action (in controller $controller) not found";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Controller class $controller not found";
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No route matched.';
        }
    }

    protected function convertToStudlyCaps($string)
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
    }

    protected function convertToCamelCase($string)
    {
        return lcfirst($this->convertToStudlyCaps($string));
    }

    protected function removeQueryStringVariables($url)
    {
        if ($url != '') {
            $parts = explode('&', $url, 2);

            if (strpos($parts[0], '=') === false) {
                $url = $parts[0];
            } else {
                $url = '';
            }
        }

        return $url;
    }

    protected function getNamespace()
    {
        $namespace = 'catalog\controller\\';

        if (array_key_exists('namespace', $this->params)) {
            $namespace .= $this->params['namespace'] . '\\';
        }

        return $namespace;
    }
}
```

To implement a central storage for objects, I have implemented this registry pattern, which is at the core of the structure.

**Registry.php**

```
<?php
final class Registry
{
    private $data = array();

    public function get($key)
    {
        return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null);
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}
```

The base/core controller further has $registry at its construct function.

**CoreController.php**

```
<?php
abstract class CoreController
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

The CoreController is extended by all app controller to inherit the properties.

**Posts.php**

```
<?php
class Posts extends CoreController
{
    public function index() {
        echo 'Hello from the index action in the posts controller';
    }

    public function addNew() {
        echo 'Hello from the addNew action in the posts controller';
    }

    public function edit() {
        echo '<p>Route parameters: <pre>'.var_dump($this->registry).'</pre></p>';
    }
}
```

To instantiate the registry and router this is the what is in the

**index.php**

```
<?php
// Instantiate registry
$registry = new \system\core\Registry();

// Database
$db = new DB(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);


$router = new \system\core\Router();
$registry->set('router', $router);


// Add the routes
$router->add('', ['controller'=>'HomeController', 'action'=>'index']);
$router->add('posts', ['controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'index']);
//$router->add('posts/new', ['controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'new']);
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');
$router->add('{controller}/{id:\d+}/{action}');
$router->add('admin/{controller}/{action}');

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

After the url `http://localhost/mvcsix/posts/1235/edit` this is what is displayed

[image]

All this looks good and works fine.

Somehow, this doesn't feel right. I var_dumped $this->registry and I have the parameters of route being displayed but I feel that to get the parameters from the route I should have var_dumped $this->router->getParams(). When I var_dump $this->router->getParams(), I get an error which says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on array in

I say this because I have the database object in the registry too and to get the query to display I do `$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members");`

Why do I have the parameters displayed on $this->registry and not on $this->router->getParams(); ?

P.S. the above code is strip down of the original code. There are namespaces and few more things which wasn't necessary for this post.

Comment: How do you instantiate `Posts` or `CoreController`? The error looks like you do it as `$controller = new Posts([])';` and therefore `registry` is an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `alex_edev` noticed, you are trying to call `get` method on an array. But where does it come from?

**What is wrong.**

`Posts` controller is initialized in the router's method `dispatch`. The url `/posts/1235/edit` does match the second route rule, so the following lines are executed

```
$controller_object = new $controller($this->params);
$action = $this->params['action'];
$action = $this->convertToCamelCase($action);
```

Pay attention to what is passed to the controller constructor. You pass route `params` property! Looking at `Posts.php`, `Posts` controller extends `CoreController`, so it expects `Registry` as a parameter of a constructor, but you pass an array - `Route::params` property. So it is the wrong object construction that brakes the party.

**Why does it work fine normally.**

Everything works fine without `var_dump` since you don't call to `Posts::__get` method. When you call `$this->router->getParams()` in `Posts` controller, it tries to get undefined `router` property with getter and fails due to wrong registry - remember, you injected an array to the controller.

**What should be done**

You should initiate controller this way

```
$controller_object = new $controller($this->registry);
```

where `registry` is injected in the `__construct`:

```
final class Router
{
    // add definition
    private $registry;

    // pass it to the router
    public function __construct($registry) {
         $this->registry = $registry;
    }
    ....
 }
```

The router is initiated as follows

```
$registry->set('db', $db);


$router = new \system\core\Router($registry);
```

So, you just need to edit 6 lines of code.

P.S. Use [Type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) to avoid that kind of errors. If you write `public function __construct(Registry $registry)` php throws a `TypeError` exception when array is passed.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted here can not be tested because it lacks `HomeController` class definition and it is also not quite clear where and at what moment `var_dump(...)` is called. But I've tried to guess your problem based on the fatal error you've mentioned and call to `var_dump()` in `edit()` function in your `Posts` class. It looks like you tried to dump `$this->router->getParams()` from that function.

"Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on array in" means that you tried to call `$arr->get()` on `$arr` that was an Array (not an Object). You have a call to such `get()` function in your CoreController's class getter. And that call is made from the scope of `$registry` property that thus should have an Object type.

So it looks like in this situation you should check the type of your `protected $registry` before trying dump `$this->router->getParams()`. It would may be not what you were expecting it to be.

I didn't find where you instantiate an object of `Posts` class in your code and what you put as a `$registry` in it's `__constructor()` so I could not check my guess. If you clarify this it would be easier to find the problem.